# Filename with a hash and Uri LocalPath handling

Tags: c#, file, uri, special-characters

I'm coding in C# and I've a URI to a file (that can be UNC, web served, etc, that's why I need to use URI) and I ran in a case where the URI is pointing to a file containing `#` in its name.

The URI is then interpreted as a fragmented one `uri.Fragment` is not empty and `uri.LocalPath` is broken, points to an hypothetical location denoted by the URI up to the hash.

1. Is there a way to make the Uri class "understand" that the `#` is part of the filename?
2. If not, how to handle this nicely because the fragment in my case contains further special characters (Kanjis) and gets escaped, so simple string operations are not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `System.UriBuilder` class.

```
UriBuilder builder1 = new UriBuilder("http://yourdomain.com/");
builder1.Path = @"hello world#シンガポール国.txt";
Uri url1 = builder1.Uri;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url1.ToString());
// -> http://yourdomain.com/hello world%23シンガポール国.txt

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url1.LocalPath);
// -> /hello world#シンガポール国.txt
```

In this case, the `Fragment` property remains blank. The URL form of the `Uri` will escape the *hash* character, since it has special meaning in that usage. The `LocalPath` property will retain the *hash* character without encoding it, since it is legal in that context.

Comment: Even with Uri it actually worked if I feed the constructor with the right (i.e. local) value... If I feed the constructor with a file:/// Uri then it's interpreted like a URL... I thought file:/// should behave like local links, that was my mistake.

Comment: Arghhh... As quite often, if something simple seems too difficult, then there is an issue with the Design!! I need to review quite a lot of places regarding this topic... Thanks!